# Counting occurrence of word in text - Apache Spark Scala

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

I originally had a set of records in the following format:

```
(Title, Text)
```

Where `Title` is the name of the book and `Text` is its description.

I have counted the occurrence of every `Word` in the `Text` field for every `Title`. It is in the following format:

```
((Word, Title), WordCount)
```

Now, I want to count the number of distinct book `Titles` that has the occurrence of a `Word` from the `Text`. And then store it in the format:

```
((Word, Title), TitleCount)
```

Where `Count` is the number of `Titles` that have this `Word`.
I want to store this in a file `TitleCount.txt`

To calculate the `TitleCount`

```
val idfRdd = yourRdd.flatMap(title => (title, scala.math.log(N/(file.filter(_.split("\t")(1).contains(title.split(",")))))))
```

Where `N = fixed number (20)`

But this code fails giving the error:

```
scala> val idfRdd = yourRdd.flatMap(title => (title, scala.math.log(N/(file.filter(_.split("\t")(1).contains(title.split(",")))))))
<console>:31: error: value split is not a member of (String, String)
       val idfRdd = yourRdd.flatMap(title => (title, scala.math.log(N/(file.filter(_.split("\t")(1).contains(title.split(",")))))))
                                                                                                                   ^
```

**UPDATE**

I tried this as well:

```
val r = splitRdd.flatMap(arr => { 
  val title = arr(0) 
  val text = arr(1) 
  val words = text.split(" ") 
  words.map(word => ((word, title), scala.math.log(N/(file.filter(_.split("\t")(1).contains(word))).count))) })
```

The above code compiles but fails at run time.

The `Title` might contain `","` but that will be a simple regex fix.
To obtain the individual word count for every Title, I wrote the following code:

```
val file = sc.textFile("s3n://bucket/test.txt") // RDD[ String ]
val splitRdd = file.map(line => line.split("\t"))    // RDD[ Array[ String ]

val yourRdd = splitRdd.flatMap(arr => {
      val title = arr(0)
      val text = arr(1)
      val words = text.split(" ")
      words.map(word => (word, title))
    })
    // RDD[ ( String, String ) ]

val countRdd = yourRdd.map(title => (title, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
countRdd.saveAsTextFile("s3n://bucket/wordcount.txt")
```

**Further Reading**

I would like to then merge both the documents `TitleCount.txt` and `WordCount.txt` by multiplying the count fields in both documents.
This gives us:

```
FinalCount.txt

((Word, Title), WordCount * TitleCount)
```

It is an actual multiplication and not for representation purposes.

Can someone help me out with this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I tried below which worked fine.

1. I created a file on `/home/cloudera/`. (please your file location).
2. scala> `val rpsteam=sc.textFile("file:///home/cloudera/RPS_Cricket_team.txt");`
3. scala> `val rpscricket=rpsteam.flatMap(lines=>lines.split(" ")).filter(value=>value=="Rahane").map(word=>(word,1)).reduceByKey(_+_);`
4. scala>`rpscricket.collect();`

Answer (score 0):

I can't guess what the datatypes are for `yourRdd`, `file`, etc, so I can't really understand your original example.

In general, to figure out these kinds of problems, split into multiple statements and declare datatypes on your variables and especially on left-side of lambdas (x:*Int* => ...).  Then the compiler or IDE will tell you where you're going astray.  If you're using an IDE, it may have a keyboard shortcut for adding a type declaration to a variable.  Learn it.  It's alt-enter for Intellij.

In this case, even though I can't understand the code as a whole, the error message is telling you that `File.filter` is returning a collection of string *tuples*, not Strings, so `_.split` doesn't work on it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error really tells it all. When you define the closure:

```
val idfRdd = yourRdd.flatMap(title => (title, scala.math.log(N/(file.filter(_.split("\t")(1).contains(title.split(",")))))))
<console>:31: error: value split is not a member of (String, String)
       val idfRdd = yourRdd.flatMap(title => (title, scala.math.log(N/(file.filter(_.split("\t")(1).contains(title.split(",")))))))
```

In particular `title => ...`, you are matching the type inside the `yourRdd` RDD. If this is your initial input, then that type is a tuple `(String, String)` which, indeed, has no spit method. You migh use `title._2` for instance.

Now, depending on the number of texts and their size, you might want to leverage spark to do the inside counts too. For instance, by doing

```
// Get an RDD[title, word], then a hashmap with all counts
val split = file.flatMap(x => x._2.split(",").map(y => (x._1, y)))
val counts = split.countByKey()
```

If what you want is to compute IDFs (I'm not entirely sure), then follow these steps:

1. Get a count of total documents: `var numDocs = file.count()`
2. Invert the split so that the word is the key.
3. Use aggregateByKey() to get an RDD with [word, num_titles]
4. map that to the final formula: `.map(x => (x._1, Log(numDocs / x._2.toDouble))`

There, you get an RDD[(Word, IDF)] :-)